# How to debug Node.js/Mocha test built with Makefile

Tags: node.js, makefile, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

How do I set up the launch.json file to debug a node.js/mochajs test that is built with a Makefile?

The tests have a script in package.json

```
"test": "make test"
```

The make script calls Mocha

```
mocha -R spec
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using the NPM launch since the eventual code is just a mocha call. I'm not happy with this answer but it lets me move forward with my work.

Original question was for Win10, finally got it to work on Mac. No idea if it works on Win10.

```
        {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Mocha Tests",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
        "args": [
            "-u",
            "tdd",
            "--timeout",
            "999999",
            "--colors",
            "${workspaceFolder}/test"
        ],
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
```